# how do you test a calculator?

Tags: testing

How will you test a calculator? Any thoughts?

thanks,

===
Sorry that I did not elaborate this question much at the beginning. Now, I want to give more backgrounds about this. This question was asked during a **technical interview** for a **programmer** position. So I suppose they were looking for some really "smart" answers or some good approach to test such application...

Thanks again.

Comment: since this is tagged 'interview'; is 'calculator' a job description? like, for people who calculate stuff? what interview questions can we ask people who calculate, to find out if they are good calculators?

Comment: Use it in the federal bank for deciding important calculations like loans to governments, money supply, etc. If after a decent amount of time, there is excessive inflation or deflation, then it's most likely the *calculator's* fault. Like most things in this world, we can't be sure though.

Comment: I once heard that one notable calculator manufacturer has over 2 million test cases for one of their models. That seems like about the proper order of magnitude for a typical calculator. So, how do you test a calculator? I think the answer is *thoroughly*

Comment: Sorry guys that I didnot give out too much information. This question was asked during an technical interview for a programmer position. So I suppose they were trying to ask about the general testing algorithms or they are looking for some really "smart" answers here..

Comment: @Jay, they may have been looking to see what kinds of questions you'd have initially, e.g. is this a basic calculator, a scientific calculator, or some other kind of calculator, and what would you say in those questions to get out the requirements to test or would you just assume 101 things that could be disastrous.

Answer (score 11):

- Exercise the interface.  Does it do what you expect?
- Exercise the functionality.  Does it do what you expect?
- Exercise boundary conditions.  Does it handle division by zero?  How does it handle really big and really small values?  Are there rounding errors that crop up?

Answer (score 4):

by throwing it against a wall, if it breaks... then it wasn't meant to be.

Comment: Haha...was calculator designed to be like this robust?

Comment: Not a bad answer!  Part of testing should be to get the app to crash and burn.

Answer (score 3):

Besides normal calculations...

Divide by zero.

Make sure negative numbers work

Check if rounding is correct

Comment: How would you make sure the normal calculations work as expected?

Comment: You would compare the results of the calculations to the results of a calculator that has been proven to work.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would want to check for border cases for every possible operation.

For example, for addition, you would check negative additions, additions involving irrational or infinite numbers etc.

For division, you would check for dividing with 0, etc.

Comment: Not only border cases, but normal cases as well. If you only test divide-by-zero, for example, how are you sure that divide-by-one and divide-by-two works?

Answer (score 0):

If you are a calculator manufacturer you will undoubtedly have a database of formulas with  known outputs for specific inputs. To test the calculator, give it the known inputs and check that it computes the known outputs.

You then also need to test that each button has the desired effect on the internal stack.

Finally, you will need to test all the non-math functionality -- does the clear button clear the display? Do your undo buttons properly undo? And so forth.